# disable contextual menu inside the paypal-api button iframe (or any iframe)

Tags: javascript, jquery, paypal

I've built a custom contextual menu and everything is working as expected; however, they decided to add a paypal button with the new API to the one page. The button is loading inside an iframe from paypal. Is there any way to disable right clicking over an external iframe?

either native javascript or jquery (only 2 options available)

this is the current code to try this but it's not working. `#paypal-button-container` is the container placed on the page paypal uses to load the iframe. `.paypal-buttons` is the class name for a div paypal creates and `.component-frame` is the iframe class name inside that `.paypal-buttons` div.

```
$('#paypal-button-container').on('contextmenu', '.paypal-buttons, .component-frame', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    console.log('Right click disabled');
});
```

They don't care about showing the custom contextual menu for the paypal, just looking for a way to turn off right clicking on the paypal button because it allows for view page source and other default browser things they don't want to show.

I obviously can't edit the paypal code but is there an option in the new API that i'm not seeing to accomplish this?

So (*for those that skip to the bottom :)*) looking for either a way to disable the contextual menu / right clicking for an iframe on my side or a paypal API option that does the same thing.

Comment: `Is there any way to disable right clicking over an external iframe?` No. What you're trying to do, amend behaviour/access in a cross-domain iframe, is not possible for security reasons.